# Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

The name of my project is 'trydjango19' and I have two apps: 'newsletter' and 'posts'.

The trydjango19/urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^posts/', include("posts.urls", namespace='posts')),
    url(r'^', include("newsletter.urls", namespace='newsletter')),]
```

The newsletter/urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', 'newsletter.views.home', name='home'),]
```

The newsletter/view.py is:

```
def home(request):
    title = 'ОСТАВЬТЕ ЗАЯВКУ'
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "title": title,
        "form": form
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)

        full_name = form.cleaned_data.get("full_name")
        if not full_name:
            full_name = "anonymous"
        instance.full_name = full_name
        instance.save()
        context = {
            "title": "Ваша заявка принята!"
    }

    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_staff:
        queryset = SignUp.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp') 
        context = {
            "queryset": queryset
        }

    return render(request, "newsletter/home.html", context)
```

The newsletter/templates/newsletter/home.html is:

```
{% extends 'newsletter/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block head_title %}Welcome | {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}

{% block jumbotron %}
    {% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}

            <img class="close" onclick="show('none')" src="{% static 'img/close.png' %}">

            <p class='lead text-align-center'>{{ title }}</p>

            <form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <p class='text-align-center'>
                    <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='Откликнуться' />
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
<img src="{% static 'img/pony.png' %}" width='380px' />
... etc.
```

I tried with urls.py in many ways, with 'namespace' and 'app_name' but I still do not understand how it should run properly

```
In template /home/pavel/DJANG/django19/src/newsletter/templates/newsletter/home.html, error at line 0
Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I surmising that you used `url` tag in `base.html` similar below:

```
{% url 'home' %}
```

but in main `urls.py` file you certained name-space for sub `urls.py` file that is in `newsletter` app.

change this `url` tag to below:

```
{% url 'newsletter:home' %}
```

Or remove namespace parameter from `url(r'^', include("newsletter.urls", namespace='newsletter')),]` line.

---

**Notice:**
Is better that set end of home url pattern, but this don't raise exception:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'newsletter.views.home', name='home'),]
```

Comment: your assumption is right, I have
    {% include 'newsletter/navbar.html' %}
in base.html
where is urls call

Comment: I wouldn't never realize such a problem. Here my thanks!